# Why Python timezone properties have lost their effect on windows?

Tags: mysql, windows, python-3.x, timezone

Some parameters:

```
# Python 3.5;
# mysqlclient 1.3.12;
# windows 10 64bit;
# mysql 5.5;
```

[image]

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Nothing's wrong with python properties what are you expecting it to do?

> timezone -- difference in seconds between UTC and local standard time

Comment: Unix-style 'Asia/Shanghai' isn't a form that's supported for the `TZ` environment variable in the Windows C runtime. See the docs for [`_tzset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/tzset). Even if you set the value to a supported format, such as "CST-8", for some reason Windows Python doesn't provide `tzset` to reinitialize the timezone without having to restart the process. The MySQLdb module appears to support reloading Python's timezone information using a Unix-style timezone format.